# Melt interior walls of oven?

Tags: temperature

What materials are used to coat the interior walls of a self cleaning oven?  Is it possible to melt the interior walls of a self-cleaning oven?  Thank you.

Comment: I believe that it's some sort of baked-on ceramic coating on metal. I think that similar technology is used to bake on ceramic coatings to the metal baskets of clothes washing machines (although the ceramics are almost certainly different). Almost certain that you will not be able to get anywhere near the melting temperature of the ceramic using the heating elements in a common household oven.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about physics

Comment: Thank you for the two very helpful and informative answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interior wall of self cleaning ovens are typically coated in vitrious enamel (also called porcelain enamel).  It has a melting point of $800^{\circ}$C to $870 ^{\circ}$C.  In the self cleaining cycle oven temperatures reach to $538^{\circ}$C.  The steel wall of the oven under the enamel coating would melt at about $1500^{\circ}$C.

So, under normal opperation the walls of the oven will not melt.  Now if you were to take a welding torch to them or something I suppose you could get them to melt.